# Creating custom designer over XML file as VSIX 2010 package

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vsix

We have a set of VS 2008 packages which leverages custom Project/Item templates, designers around XML files for our in house product development using VS. We are planning to move to VS 2010 and looking for migrating our VS 2008 packages to 2010. I see that there has been a rewrite of VS from ground up using WPF/MEF, but still could not figure out how we can leverage it for our packages. I am seeing some guidelines, samples and community material on how we should be extending the VS 2010 WPF based text editor, but could not find any reference implementations on how one should implement a custom designer on top of XML using the WPF/MEF APIs of VS SDK.

Only sample I have come across regards to any custom designer implementation so far was Example.XmlWpfDesigner - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Designer-View-Over-XML-20a81f17 which does not talk anything about WPF/MEF way of doing custom designers.

Has anybody come across any reference implementations along these lines? Any help regarding this would be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Siva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample you linked to is the right one to be looking at for a designer over an XML file. It is a WPF-design surface that edits VSTemplate XML files.

The only part of the VS API's that moved to MEF in VS 2010 was the core text editor. While you are welcome to use MEF for the implementation details of your designer, you'll still need to talk to the VS COM API's to do things like buffer management, interfacing with Source Control interfaces, etc...

Comment: Thanks @aaron-marten for confirming this. We were indeed thinking going this direction.